# How to store the text of the row which contains the radiobutton 'on'?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I need to automate the store a row's text on selenium IDE. The row is not always the same. The row to be stored is the unique which contains a radiobutton selected.

The path for the button is (where 'x' is an integer variable):

```
//table[@id='wttrAddressees']/tbody/tr[x]/td[2]/input
```

I can find the selected button with:

```
//input[@checked='checked']
```

or

```
//input[@checked]
```

This works, but is not dynamic:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>//table[@id='wttrAddressees']/tbody/tr[2]</td>
    <td>rowText</td>
</tr>
```

Is there a way to store the xpath (not a node) of a given webElement?

Thanks,

PS  - The test is all in html code.

Comment: Can you provide the actual html for the node you are trying to select? The code you provided doesn't help much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the target row dynamically by selected radio button as follows :

```
//table[@id='wttrAddressees']/tbody/tr[td/input[@checked='checked']]
```

The XPath should return `<tr>` element where `<td>` child element has child `<input>` element checked.

Comment: It works perfectly whatever the line with the radiobutton 'on' is.